# Questions about navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

1. I am confused about the relationship of navigation controller and content view controllers. In storyboard, navigation bar is under the navigation controller, so I linked it to the `NavigationController` class and then customized the navigation bar in the `viewDidLoad` function. However, since different content views will have different navigation bar, like different bar buttons, how can I realize this? Just some basic ideas are good enough. My guess is that I need to specify specific bar buttons in specific content view controllers, but since the `navigationBar` property is in `NavigationController` class, how can I refer to it?
2. I want to hide the title of the navigation bar and make the bar only show some custom buttons (I know toolbar may match it better, but I have other reasons to adopt navigation bar). Please tell me how to hide the title in detail and swift language is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Every ViewController instance has a `navigationController` property, it' just an optional. To set the bar buttons, you'll want to use `navigationItem`. So to specify bar buttons you either do so in Interface builder per view controller, or just or do something like this in viewDidLoad

```
let navBarButton = UIBarButtonItem()...set up bar button
self.navigationItem?.leftBarButtonItem = navBarButton
```

2) Hiding the title is trivial:

```
self.navigationItem?.title = ""
```

Comment: So that means I don't need to create a `NavigationController` class additionally, right? Or I can still use it to make some common customizations?

Comment: You can customize each instance of a navbar inside the view controller of you can use the appearance proxy to edit all of them, typically done inside the app delegate.